# CURL command line with parameters

Tags: shell, curl, command-line, wsdl, command-prompt

Maybe thats a stupid question, but I am stopped because of this. I have the WSDL structure that is the following as the image:

```
           <wsdl:types>
                <xsd:schema attributeFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="urn:sap-com:document:sap:rfc:functions">
                    <xsd:simpleType name="char10">
                        <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
                            <xsd:maxLength value="10"/>
                        </xsd:restriction>
                    </xsd:simpleType>
                    <xsd:simpleType name="char17">
                        <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
                            <xsd:maxLength value="17"/>
                        </xsd:restriction>
                    </xsd:simpleType>
                    <xsd:simpleType name="char5">
                        <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
                            <xsd:maxLength value="5"/>
                        </xsd:restriction>
                    </xsd:simpleType>
                    <xsd:simpleType name="char6">
                        <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
                            <xsd:maxLength value="6"/>
                        </xsd:restriction>
                    </xsd:simpleType>
                    <xsd:simpleType name="string">
                        <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string"/>
                    </xsd:simpleType>
                    <xsd:complexType name="AUTH">
                        <xsd:sequence>
                            <xsd:element name="TIPO" type="tns:char6"/>
                            <xsd:element name="USERNAME" type="tns:char10"/>
                            <xsd:element name="PASSWORD" type="tns:char10"/>
                        </xsd:sequence>
                    </xsd:complexType>
                    <xsd:element name="ASK">
                        <xsd:complexType>
                            <xsd:sequence>
                                <xsd:element name="AUTHENTICATION" type="tns:AUTH"/>
                                <xsd:element name="REQUEST_NUMBER_IN" type="tns:char17"/>
                            </xsd:sequence>
                        </xsd:complexType>
                    </xsd:element>
                    <xsd:element name="MY_RESP">
                        <xsd:complexType>
                            <xsd:sequence>
                                <xsd:element name="PENDING" type="tns:string"/>
                                <xsd:element name="PHOTO" type="tns:string"/>
                                <xsd:element name="REQUEST_NUMBER_OUT" type="tns:char17"/>
                                <xsd:element name="STATUS" type="tns:char5"/>
                            </xsd:sequence>
                        </xsd:complexType>
                    </xsd:element>
                </xsd:schema>
            </wsdl:types>
```

It is a must doing this first connection with curl in cmd (dont ask me why)
The command I am trying is:

```
curl "http://URL?username=user&password=pwd&tipo=0" --data @file.wsdl
```

But I get a message from the server that the login is wrong. What I want to ask is, am I filling the parameters correct?

Comment: @Quasímodo, I dont know if I understand. 
In the WSDL?
The file is waiting for input, an AUTH that needs type, username and password, and then it needs a request_number_in
The second block, in My_Resp is the server response data structure

Comment: See [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557) for why you shouldn't post screenshots of code. Looks like you have an extra quote in your curl command though

Comment: @thatotherguy sure, i'm sorry and thanks. The quote was my fault, I took it to not put the entire link

Comment: It's hard to say if you're filling in the parameters correctly without looking at the documentation of the API you're hitting.

Comment: @AndreyKaipov, thats my problem, I dont have access to the docs. They only gave me the WSDL, they gave me the user and pass (that I believe its wrong, I send an email already) and said to try to get the response with that wsdl

Answer (score 0):

There is a chance that your password may contain non-alphabetic characters and your shell is interpreting them [accordingly to its special function](https://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/special-chars.html) instead of just reading your input as a simple, shell meaningless string. If that is the case, try to [escape them](https://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_03_03.html) and check if that is your issue.

Comment: its not the case :/ its a "clean" password, only with letters and numbers